# Angular 5 element added to array gets deleted somehow

Tags: angular

I have a competition manager application and when a competition is created it is added to a mockdata array. It does add it to the array but when I try to view the competition is somehow gets deleted.

Code for creating a competition in the component:

```
const competition = new Competition();
competition.id = COMPETITIONS.length;
competition.name = this.competition_name;
competition.users = this.userArr;

this.competitionService.createCompetition(competition).subscribe(data => {
    this.router.navigate(['/competition/index']);
});
```

Code in the service to get and create competition:

```
getCompetition(id: number): Observable<Competition> {
    return of(COMPETITIONS.find(competition => Number(competition.id) === Number(id)));
}

createCompetition(competition): Observable<number> {
    return of(COMPETITIONS.push(competition));
}
```

Code to view a specific competition:

```
this.competitionService.getCompetition(route.snapshot.params.id).subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
        this.competition = data;
    } else {
        router.navigate(['/competition/index']);
    }
});
```

Competition mockdata:

```
import {Competition} from '../classes/competition';
import {USERS} from './mock-users';

export const COMPETITIONS: Competition[] = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Testje Compie', users: [USERS[0], USERS[3]]}
];
```

Comment: Can you include the declaration of `COMPETITIONS`? It is likely that that is stored in a place that is getting reset during navigation

Comment: seems like you are routing same component again. try to console log route.snapshot.params.id before making service call. is it giving expected id everytime?

Comment: @Vlad274 I added the mockdata file which I use in the service to get all the competitions. This is getting resetted everytime I think yes.

Comment: @PavanShukla yes, it is giving the right id

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the mockdata via a standard `import`, that is likely the source of your issue. To make sure that the data persists as you navigate through the application, you should store the collection in the service itself.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Competition } from '../classes/competition';
import { USERS } from './mock-users';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CompetitionsService {

  public COMPETITIONS: Competition[] = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Testje Compie', users: [USERS[0], USERS[3]]}
  ];

  constructor() { }

  getCompetition(id: number): Observable<Competition> {
      return of(this.COMPETITIONS.find(competition => Number(competition.id) === Number(id)));
  }

  createCompetition(competition): Observable<number> {
      return of(this.COMPETITIONS.push(competition));
  }
}
```

---

If you really want to keep the mockdata declaration in the separate file, than you can change the service to use that

```
import { COMPETITIONS } from "competition.mockdata"

export class CompetitionsService {
  public COMPETITIONS = COMPETITIONS;
  [...]
}
```